# reshape a matrix from [?, 100] to [batch_size, ?, 100]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm building an autoencoder based on RNN. After FC layer, I have to reshape my output to `[batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dimension]`. However, my sequence `length(timestep)` for my decoder is uncertain. What I wish is something work as follow.

```
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [batch_size, None, word_dimension])
```

Or, is there any other way for me to get the sequence length from the input data which has a shape `[batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dimension]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-1` for the dimension in your reshape operation that you want to be calculated automatically.

For example, here:

```py
x = tf.zeros((100 * 10 *12,))
reshaped = tf.reshape(x, [100, -1, 12])
```

`reshaped` will have shape `(100, 10, 12)`

> Or, is there any other way for me to get the sequence length from the input data which has a shape [batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dimension].

You can use the `tf.shape` operation to find the shape of a tensor at runtime so if you want `sequence_length` in a tensor with shape `[batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dimension]`, you need just call `tf.shape(x)[1]`.

For my example above, calling:

```py
tf.shape(reshaped)[1]
```

would give an `int32` tensor with shape `()` and value `10`

Comment: @carinaxu you are welcome. :-) If it helped you can always accept and/or upvote the answer